# Getting Error in Azure Logic Apps in HTTP POST :- "BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON."

Tags: azure, http, post, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic App in Azure which uses `HTTP Action Connector` to POST request to a REST API.

The JSON body of this request looks like below:-

```
{
            "id": 40,
            "salutation": "Mr",
            "firstName": "Smith",
            "lastName": "Jack",
            "ageRange": "18-20",
            "gender": "male",
            "emailAddress": "atet4gsg@gmail.com",
            "phone": "3532523523",
            "phoneType": "mobile",
            "addressStreet": "1234",
            "addressCity": "gagdgd",
            "addressCounty": "gadgg",
            "addressCountry": "UK",
            "addressPostcode": "235dgds",
            "preferredContactMethod": "email",
            "leadType": "sales",
            "leadForm": "brochure",
            "dealerId": 1111,
            "dealerDepartment": "New Vehicle Sales",
            "externalSalepersonName": "3532532",
            "leadCurrency": "GBP",
            "leadMin": 1000,
            "leadMax": 150000,
            "leadStatus": "New",
            "interestInAccessories": "yes",
            "interestInFinance": "yes",
            "interestInInsurance": "yes",
            "interestInPurchase": "yes",
            "comments": "Test",
            "vehicleModelYear": 2019,
            "vehicleBodyStyle": "saloon",
            "vehicleEngineType": 2,
            "vehicleFuelType": "petrol",
            "transmission": "manual",
            "exteriorColour": "Brown",
            "interiorColour": "Brown",
            "make": "2019",
            "modelDescription": "A-Class",
            "modelYear": 2019,
            "vin": "353253",
            "registrationNumber": "2532532532",
            "odometerReading": 53,
            "serviceDate": "2019-12-04",
            "price": 53253,
            "vinVerified": "no",
            "sentToPOS": "no"
        }
```

It initially worked for me but now somehow I have started getting an error as `"BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON."`

Please help if anyone has any idea about this issue.

[image]

Comment: Your json data is ok, so please provide more information about your flow.

Comment: Did you provides Content-Type: application/json as HTTP Header?

Comment: Both I have test, if don't add the header, default is application/json; charset=utf-8. So what settings you set?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: This issue has been resolved. The problem was with the API I was requesting was not returning the response in the valid json format. Hence, logic app was failing while formatting the HTTP response. Thank you both for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. The problem was with the API I was requesting was not returning the response in the valid json format. Hence, logic app was failing while formatting the HTTP response. Thank you both for your replies.